# Запуск программы от имени администратора

Tags: windows, uac, файловая-система

Здравствуйте.

Как можно произвести автоматический запуск программы от имени администратора в системе Windows? Такая потребность возникла в процессе работы с файловой системой на компьютере, где локальными дисками владеет система и имеет к ним полный доступ только она. Я пытаюсь скопировать текстовый файл в папку Program Files, к примеру, но ничего не получается, потому что недостаточно прав, хотя вход в систему произвел под администраторской учетной записью( UAC мешает ). Как быть в этом случае? Обязательно ли иметь права администратора или есть другие способы?

Благодарю...

Comment: Попробуй так: [учетная запись Administrator в Windows 7][1].


  [1]: http://www.wseven.info/administrator/

Comment: Нуууу! Что это вообще такое? Надо это делать программно.

Comment: `UAC мешает` — он не мешает, а предупреждает потенциальное заражение. Административные права нужны только административным утилитам и установщикам для проведения общесистемных изменений, да вредоносному ПО для установки собственных драйверов. То есть появление UAC-овского предупреждения должно как минимум насторожить обычного пользователя. Но из-за манеры горе-программ писать настройки куда не положено, этот рубеж системы стал назойливым и абсолютно бесполезным.

Answer (score 3):

Можно в manifest [прописать](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384691.aspx) автоматический запрос прав на подобные операции.

/MANIFESTUAC (Embeds UAC information in manifest)

Comment: Вот, кстати, тоже неплохое решение. Оно даже немного удобнее моего. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Повторюсь, что мое решение данной проблемы заключалось в имитации "пользовательского" запуска программы от имени администратора( клик правой кнопкой мыши по exe-файлу и выбор "Запуск от имени администратора" ). После этих действий система тупо вызывает команду ShellExecute( опять же кэп! ) с параметром `"runas"`. Вот реализация сказанного через более расширенный способ запуска с использованием структуры `TShellExecuteInfo`:

```
var
 SEI: TShellExecuteInfo;
 lpExitCode: DWORD;  // не обязательно. Код завершения процесса открытой программы.
begin
 ZeroMemory(@SEI, SizeOf(SEI));  // обнуляем память на всякий случай
 SEI.cbSize := SizeOf(TShellExecuteInfo);
 SEI.Wnd := Handle;   // родительское окошко( можно установить в NULL )
 SEI.fMask := SEE_MASK_FLAG_DDEWAIT or SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI;
 SEI.lpVerb := PChar('runas');   // админ - права!
 SEI.lpFile := PChar(Application.ExeName);
 SEI.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
 SEI.lpParameters:= '';
 if ShellExecuteEx(@SEI) then
   GetExitCodeProcess(SEI.hProcess, lpExitCode);   // код завершения процесса.
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Для Windows 8, 10**

Правой кнопкой по приложению, выбираем пункт в меню "Исправление проблем с совместимостью" ([пункты меню на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12859334/5454565))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Ждём окончания сканирования...
2. Выбираем "Диагностика программы";
3. Выбираем галку "Для программы необходимы дополнительные разрешения";
4. Жмём "Далее"
5. Нажимаем "Проверить программу..." - приложение будет запущено с запросом прав админа;
6. Разрешаем запуск приложения в окне запроса прав UAC;
7. Закрываем приложение, возвращаемся к окну "Устранение проблем с совместимостью";
8. Жмём "Далее...";
9. Выбираем "Да, сохранить эти параметры для программы";
10. Готово. Закрываем окошко.
    Теперь выбранное приложение будет запускаться от имени администратора по умолчанию.

**Для Windows < 8**

Через ярлык

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Делаем ярлык на приложение;
2. Идём в "Свойства" ярлыка;
3. Жмём "Дополнительно...";
4. Выбираем галку "Запуск от имени администратора";
5. Жмём "ОК", "Применить";

Comment: Что за тенденция отвечать на древние вопросы?